# Animate region change in MapKit SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am showing a map with SwiftUI. The user has a button in the map. When the user presses on that map, the map should show the current location of the user.

The problem is that the map jumps right to the current location without an animation. I want to animate the change, is it possible? This is how I create my map:

```
Map(coordinateRegion: $locationManager.region, showsUserLocation: true)
```

Comment: Wrap the change in a `withAnimation()` block.

Comment: @Yrb how? I can not get it working

Comment: I can't tell you. You didn't post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't now how or where you are changing your region.

Comment: Umm, I did test it. Just not on your code since you didn't provide your code. SwiftUI Maps are not difficult to implement in about 30 seconds.

Comment: @Yrb Sure you got it working... XD

Answer (score 8):

The `withAnimation` should wrap the code block which updates the `$locationManager.region` value. In your case, below will work.

```
Button {
  withAnimation {
     // code updating locationManager.region
  }    
} label: {
            
}
```